# Showing images from multi-page gallery in continuous lightbox

Tags: php, html, image-gallery

I was looking for a solution for using a lightbox where it is possible to see all images while these images are spread over multiple pages like in a multi-paged gallery (page 1-2-3-...).

Now I can only see the images in the lightbox that are on the current page what is - offcourse - perfectly normal.
What tips or tricks are there to still be able to scroll over all the images I have?

```
    <div class="row" id="gallery">
        <?php
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $images_per_page;
        $end = $start + $images_per_page;
        if ($end > $total) {
            $end = $total;
        }
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php print '/upload/files/'.basename($images[$i]); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php print '/upload/.thumbs/files/'.basename($images[$i]); ?>" alt="Restaurant De Clochard"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
            <?php if ($page > 1) { ?>
                <a href="/galerij?page=<?php print $page - 1; ?>">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>
                    vorige pagina
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
            <?php if ($total_pages > $page) { ?>
                <a href="/galerij?page=<?php print $page + 1; ?>">
                    volgende pagina
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```